# How can you limit RAM consumption in a process?

Tags: c, linux, ram

How can you limit the physical memory consumption of a C program from within the source code on a linux 2.6.32 machine?

I need to determine the type of page replacement algorithm the system is using.

The problem is that without limiting the number of pages a process can have in memory, it becomes difficult to analyze the pattern of page faults to determine the page replacement algorithm.

Also, I don't have root access on the machine.

Comment: You may need to use system quotas to limit the amount of RAM a process may use.

Answer (score 5):

`setrlimit(RLIMIT_MEMLOCK, ...)`.

Comment: Could you explain more?  I thought MEMLOCK only affected how many pages you could forcibly stop from being swapped out?  I want pages to be swapped out, because I need to analyze the swap pattern to determine what algorithm is being used.

Comment: From which include this function comes from? `man setrlmit` returns nothing.

Comment: @karl: The function name is misspelled in this answer, which likely explains why `man` can't find it.  Try `setrlimit` with two 'i' s.

Comment: @ktbiz: It affects how many can be locked *in* to memory. If you just want to limit the size of the data segment, you'd use RLIMIT_DATA instead. If you want to limit its total virtual memory usage, that would be RLIMIT_AS.